# Show that the map $T(x)=x/2+x^{-1}$ is a contraction and find $\alpha$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=[1,\infty)$. Show that the map $T(x)=x/2+x^{-1}$ is a contraction, and find $\alpha$.

Proof: A function $T:X \rightarrow X$ is said to be a contraction if

$dist(T(x),T(y)) \leq \alpha dist(x,y)$ for some $0< \alpha <1$.

Observe that $T'(x)=1/2-x^{-2}<0$ when $ x \geq 1$.

By the Mean Value Theorem,

$|T(x)-T(y)|=|T'(c)(x-y)|=|T'(c)| \dot |x-y|<|x-y|$ where $c \epsilon (x,y)$ 
for all $x,y \epsilon [1,\infty)$

However, I need equality as well how do I get there

Comment: You are almost there.  Just note that $\sup_{x \geq 1} |T^\prime (x)| = 1/2.$

Comment: I agree with your statement but I still don't see how I would implement it

Comment: $|T(x) - T(y)| \leq \sup_{x \in [1, \infty)} |T^\prime (x)||x -y|$ so since $X$ is complete and $T$ is a contraction because, $|T(x) - T(y)| \leq 1/2 |x -y|$ so we may invoke the fixed point theorem with $\alpha = 1/2$ to conclude that $T$ does have a fixed point.

Comment: Thank you. I just figured it out right now. How would I find $\alpha$